# Google Play order id uniqueness

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, orders, merchant-account

Currently, Google Play order IDs have this format: `GPA.XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXX`
Previously, they was like: `{merchant_id}.{order_id_number}` - and it was pretty unique across all merchant accounts.

But, now, i have doubts about uniqueness of order IDs in that new 'GPA...' format. 
Here i speaking exactly about **GLOBAL** uniqueness (across all accounts), but not about uniqueness across one specific account.

So, are they globally unique or not? I couldn't found information about that...

Thank you!